# TS2305 when nested tag is different

Tags: javascript, typescript, git, npm, tags

**TL;DR:**

```
dependencies:
- another-package
  - commonly-used-types#1 (tag 1)
- commonly-used-types#2 (tag 2)
```

added code:

```js
import { MyClass } from 'commonly-used-types';
```

Build failed. Import of `commonly-used-types` points `#1`, not `#2`. There's no `MyClass` on `#1`.

> error TS2305: Module '"../../../../../../../../../Users/devheedoo/Dev/actual-project/node_modules/another-package/node_modules/commonly-used-types/dist"' has no exported member 'MyClass'

---

**Details:**

We use 2 repositories. One for commonly used types, and one for actual project.

We add and export `MyClass` interface to type repository, then add git tag #2.

```js
// commomnly-used-types repository
export interface MyClass { ... }
```

We import `MyClass` interface to actual project repository.

```js
// actual-project repository
import { MyClass } from 'commonly-used-types';

const myClass = new MyClass();
// ...
```

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "another-package": "git+ssh://git@github.com/username/another-package"
    "commonly-used-types": "git+ssh://git@github.com/username/commonly-used-types.git#2"
  }
}
```

But we got the following error:

> error TS2305: Module '"../../../../../../../../../../../Users/choco/Dev/actual-project/node_modules/another-package/node_modules/commonly-used-types/dist"' has no exported member 'MyClass'

There another package uses older tag(#1) of commonly-used-types.

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "commonly-used-types": "git+ssh://git@github.com/username/commonly-used-types.git#1"
  }
}
```

---

**Question:**

We could fix it using detail path:

```js
// before
import { MyClass } from 'commonly-used-types';

// after
import { MyClass } from './node_modules/commonly-used-types/dist';
```

But I wonder why the import statement points `commonly-used-types` in another package's node_modules?

To use only package name for import, should we sync tag of `commonly-used-types` in another-package every time the tag updates?

---

Why TS compiler search commonly-used-types

from `/node_modules/another-package/node_modules/commonly-used-types/dist`,

not `/node_modules/commonly-used-types/dist`?

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid, but I notice your "manual" import starts with `./dist/node_modules` whereas the (censored) path in the error is: `devheedoo/Dev/actual-project/node_modules/another-package/node_modules/commonly-used-types` which doesn't seem like it ever has a `node_modules` inside of a `dist`. Are you expecting it to reach inside the `dist` folder?

Comment: I didn't think it deeply. I will check this error on this point of view!